# Best Practice: Nested ForEach

Tags: c#, nested-loops

Is there a best practice for the number of nested "foreach"?

That is I'm spiraling into nested "foreach" over Complex dictionaries, is there a point where it starts to produce overhead that "COULD" impede performance? Is this something even worth considering.

To make it specific and not open to being subjective:
I have 3 Complex Dictionaries that look like this;

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, XObject>()
Dictionary<string, List<YObject>()
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<ZObjects>()
```

Obviously now, as I filter these Dictionary (in a foreach), to produce the data I'm looking for, the structure of my code is heading towards 5 Nested "foreach" excluding the Outer 1. In answering these are the areas I'm worried might be impacted:

1. **Performance** (too many context switches)
2. **Memory** (retaining all the datasets in memory at a given instant)
3. **Maintainability** (bad programmer!)

Best practice or doesn't matter?

Comment: With this kind of structure, consider creating some custom classes that encapsulate and describe the data better.

Comment: @Oded i think the problem will still be the same. It will only be more readable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. There is no "context switch" for a foreach statement.
2. Memory: quite irrelevant, the memory is taken by data not by Enumerators (used by foreach statements)
3. Maintanability: Consider refactoring your code adding methods to perform items

Answer (score 3):

A clear and concise way to achieve this, would be to functionally separate them.  Consider:

```
// represents outer loop
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Operation1(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> input)
{
   // outer loop processing
   IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> output = Operation2(input);
   return output;
}

// which feeds in to...

IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Operation2(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> input)
{
    // work on it
   IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> output = Operation3(input);
   return output;
}

// and finally

IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Operation3(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> input)
{
    // work on it
    return input;
}
```

This keeps the functionality of the loops separate, the order can be changed, and each one is a discreet unit of work.